# Does radiation have any effects besides lowering maximum health?

Tags: fallout-4

In FO3 radiation functioned by essentially adding negative perks, which lowered your SPECIAL scores, or affected other stats.  In FO4, radiation just seems to limit your maximum health until removed.  Are there any other effects besides this in FO4?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Fallout 4, unless you take certain perks like [Ghoulish](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Ghoulish), radiation simply reduces your maximum health. It has no other effects. The rate appears to be 1% of your health decreased per 10 RADs.

Comment: Well, there are also the [Ghoulish perks](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Ghoulish), which makes radiation heal you... but also reduce your maximum health.  Not a particularly useful set of perks as far as I'm concerned, but it does add a different effect for radiation, strictly speaking.